# Entity Framework joining 2 tables, but with 2 queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 tables:

**Flights**:

```
FlightNumber | FromCodeIata | ToCodeIata | ....
```

**Airports**:

```
Iata | Icao | City | Name
```

When I want is a combined table with:

```
FlightNumber | FromCodeIata | FromCodeIcao | FromCity | FromName |
ToCodeIata | ToCodeIcao | ToCity | ToName | ...
```

So the `FromIata` should join and the `ToIata` too.

How can I do this using Entity Framework?

```
 var query = context.Flights
                   .Join(context.Airports, 
                         p => p.FromCodeIata, 
                         e => e.CodeIata, 
                         (p, e)  => new {
                                            p.FlightNumber, 
                                            FromCodeIata  = e.CodeIata, 
                                            FromCodeIcao = e.CodeIcao, 
                                            FromName = e.Name, 
                                        }).ToList();
```

Thanks

Comment: Generating JOINs is the job of EF, not the developer. If you have to use JOINs, something is wrong with your model. Which you didn't post. EF  deals with objects, not tables. Your `Flight` should have an `Airport` property. In that case all you'd have to do is write `context.Flights.Select(f=>new {f.FlightNumber, IataCode=f.Airport.IataCode, IcaoCode=f.Airport.IcaoCode});`. Of course, a flight never has just one airport, it has two or more (if there are any stops) so you need to clear up your requirements. Perhaps you need a `Departure` and `Arrival` property? Or an `Airports` prop?

Comment: BTW I work for an OTA. Don't do manual joins. Flights and airports are a lot more complicated than what you posted, and littering your code with manual joins is going to make things a mess *really* fast.